# Undefined variable in php project

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to php and html and I keep getting this annoying error.  Everything looks perfectly fine to me but it clearly isn't.  If anyone could bother explaining to me or pointing out the obvious, I'd appreciate it.

The error reads that there is an undefined variable at $reviews

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT rt FROM userhelp WHERE user_id != ? AND project_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $project_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rt);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $reviews[] = $rt;              
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $reviews;           <------The error is right here
```

Comment: This error is quite self explanatory. Just define it before you want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `$reviews` before while loop.

```
$reviews = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $reviews[] = $rt;              
}

$stmt->close();
return $reviews;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the array before the loop. Why? In the event there are no results, the while loop does never get executed and the array is never defined. Plus it is bad coding practice to not define the array first (for this exact reason).

```
$reviews = array();
while( [...]
```